# Difference between the different versions of .Net

Tags: .net

I checked what version of Microsoft's .Net platform I have, and I saw that it is 4.0. I know there are newer versions. I found a book about WPF applications but it is explained how to write the apps on C# .Net 4.5. Now, does that mean that I can't write and test the examples of the book? 
And for example if I write an application on .Net 4.5, but user's computer has 4.0 version, will he be able to run this app?

Comment: This question is way too broad. However, **most** code which runs on .NET 4.5 will work on .NET 4. However, when you build an application you target a specific version of the framework, which the user must have at minimum in order to run your program.

Comment: Time to go and read more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the examples should work just fine in framework 4.0, or even framework 3.0. Some features require a later version than 3.0, like for example LINQ that requires 3.5.

The computer where you run the application has to have a framework version that is the same or later than the version that the application was created for. An application created for 4.0 will run on both 4.0 and 4.5, but an application created for 4.5 won't run on 4.0.

Comment: For example if I make an application that uses LINQ and I send it to a friend who has a .Net 2.0, will the application run?

Comment: @user2972343: No, that won't run. You have to compile it for at least version 3.5 to use LINQ, and then the computer running it also have to have at least that version.

Comment: Wasn't WPF released with 3.0?

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, you are correct. Thanks, I adjusted the answer.